# Strongly Typed String

Tags: c#, string, design-patterns, types

## The Setting

I have a prototype class `TypedString<T>` that attempts to "strongly type" (dubious meaning) strings of a certain category. It uses the C#-analogue of the [curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

### `class TypedString<T>`

```
public abstract class TypedString<T>
    : IComparable<T>
    , IEquatable<T>
    where T : TypedString<T>
{
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    protected virtual StringComparison ComparisonType
    {
        get { return StringComparison.Ordinal; }
    }

    protected TypedString(string value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        this.Value = Parse(value);
    }

    //May throw FormatException
    protected virtual string Parse(string value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public int CompareTo(T other)
    {
        return string.Compare(this.Value, other.Value, ComparisonType);
    }

    public bool Equals(T other)
    {
        return string.Equals(this.Value, other.Value, ComparisonType);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is T && Equals(obj as T);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}
```

The `TypedString<T>` class can now be used to eliminate code duplication when defining a bunch of different "string categories" throughout my project. An example simple usage of this class is in defining a `Username` class:

### `class Username` (example)

```
public class Username : TypedString<Username>
{
    public Username(string value)
        : base(value)
    {
    }

    protected override string Parse(string value)
    {
        if (!value.Any())
            throw new FormatException("Username must contain at least one character.");
        if (!value.All(char.IsLetterOrDigit))
            throw new FormatException("Username may only contain letters and digits.");
        return value;
    }
}
```

This now lets me use the `Username` class throughout my whole project, never having to check if a username is correctly formatted - if I have an expression or variable of type `Username`, it's **guaranteed** to be correct (or null).

#### Scenario 1

```
string GetUserRootDirectory(Username user)
{
    if (user == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
    return Path.Combine(UsersDirectory, user.ToString());
}
```

I don't have to worry about formatting of the user string here - I already know it's correct by nature of the type.

#### Scenario 2

```
IEnumerable<Username> GetFriends(Username user)
{
    //...
}
```

Here the caller knows what it's getting as the return just based on the type. An `IEnumerable<string>` would require reading into the details of the method or documentation. Even worse, if someone were to change the implementation of `GetFriends` such that it introduces a bug and produces invalid username strings, that error could silently propagate to callers of the method and wreak all kinds of havoc. This nicely typed version prevents that.

#### Scenario 3

`System.Uri` is an example of a class in .NET that does little more than wrap a string that has a huge number of formatting constraints and helper properties/methods for accessing useful parts of it. So that's one piece of evidence that this approach isn't totally crazy.

## The Question

I imagine this kind of thing has been done before. I already see the benefits of this approach and don't need to convince myself any more.

**Is there a downside I may be missing?
Is there a way this could come back to bite me later?**

Comment: To me this is just object oriented programming with a different name.  `TypedString<UserName>` or `UserName` classes can be functionally the same if `UserName` is written correctly -- TypedString just gives you an enforced inheritance pattern.

Comment: @Hogan I probably should have mentioned that the point of this was that I have *lots* of theses "string categories." I want to keep the code duplication to a minimum when defining all of the `TypedString<T>` inheriting types, which is why I'm doing it this way. (usernames, cross-platform path tokens, user group names, etc - the list goes on)

Comment: @TimothyShields: agreed regarding the Meters example, in the general sense.  But if you were writing a unit conversion program or perhaps scientific software (lunar lander module!? -:) )  then something like a Meters class would be extremely useful and warranted.  It would prevent someone from using a Miles instance where a Meters was required.. or better yet, with a little operator overloading it could *automatically* convert the miles to meters.  The point is, use (or abuse) data types AS NEEDED.

Comment: I would hope your peers would not get upset about Meters if it was needed for the Application domain.  This is exactly the point of Design finding what is write for the situation your worry is about over design which is a good worry.  This question can't be answered because we don't really know the application domain in question.  (edit - @Dan-o hit my point exactly)

Comment: @TimothyShields - I wonder about this keeping code to a minimum - much of the code listed already exists in string -- aren't you just duplicating?

Comment: "I imagine this kind of thing has been done before. I already see the benefits of this approach and don't need to convince myself any more." - I don't see the benefits of having string validation code spewed around different "classes" that really have no behavior other than to validate strings. If I were tasked with maintaining this nonsense, I'd be quite annoyed to find that those string validations weren't handled at serialization/deserialization boundaries.

Comment: I believe the preferred nomenclature is "stringly typed"

Comment: @RitchMelton Given your tone, I suppose you're the downvoter? It seems inappropriate to downvote instead of just answering the question. If you have some definite downsides to this approach, express them that way. (The downvote button says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.") - To address your point: the classes inheriting from `TypedString<T>` ***are*** the serialization/deserialization boundaries (`ToString` is serialize and `Parse` is deserialize).

Comment: @TimothyShields - I didn't downvote. I don't think its a bad question. I just don't think the approach is useful. YMMV.

Comment: user414076: This is the **opposite** of stringly typed, since this is about defining object representations from string representations.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a particularly egregious use of the curiously recurring pattern in C#; this kind of pattern is pretty common and fairly understandable.  Had you said `abstract class TypedString<T> where T : TypedString<T>` then things start to get a bit harder to understand.

Comment: @EricLippert I'm certainly not the authority on whether it is or not. :) I was just going by what I saw [here (link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern#General_form) as an example of CRTP. If in my code you rename the type parameter `T` to `Derived`, it exactly matches the example given on that Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## General Thoughts

I'm not fundamentally against the approach (and kudos for knowing/using the CRTP, which can be quite useful). The approach allows metadata to be wrapped around a single value, which can be a very good thing. It's extensible too; you can add additional data to the type without breaking interfaces.

I don't like the fact that your current implementation seems to depend heavily on exception-based flow. This may be perfectly appropriate for some things or in truly exceptional cases. However, if a user was trying to pick a valid username, they could potentially throw dozens of exceptions in the process of doing so.

Of course, you could add exception-free validation to the interface. You must also ask yourself where you *want* the validation rules to live (which is always a challenge, especially in distributed applications).

## WCF

Speaking of "distribution": consider the implications of implementing such types as part of a WCF data contract. Ignoring the fact that data contracts should usually expose simple DTOs, you also have the problem of proxy classes which will maintain your type's properties, but not its implementation.

Of course, you can mitigate this by placing the parent assembly on both client and server. In some cases, this is perfectly appropriate. In other cases, less so. Let's say that the validation of one of your strings required a call to a database. This would most likely not be appropriate to have in both the client/server locations.

## "Scenario 1"

It sounds like you are seeking consistent formatting. This is a worthy goal and works great for things like URIs and perhaps usernames. For more complex strings, this can be a challenge. I've worked on products where even "simple" strings can be formatted in many different ways depending on context. In such cases, dedicated (and perhaps reusable) formatters may be more appropriate.

Again, very situation-specific.

## "Scenario 2"

> Even worse, if someone were to change the implementation of GetFriends
>   such that it introduces a bug and produces invalid username strings,
>   that error could silently propagate to callers of the method and wreak
>   all kinds of havoc.

```
IEnumerable<Username> GetFriends(Username user) { }
```

I can see this argument. A few things come to mind:

- A better method name: `GetUserNamesOfFriends()`
- Unit/integration testing
- Presumably these usernames are validated when they are created/modified. If this is your own API, why wouldn't you trust what it gives you?

Side note: when dealing with people/users, an immutable ID is probably more useful (people like changing usernames).

## "Scenario 3"

> System.Uri is an example of a class in .NET that does little more than
>   wrap a string that has a huge number of formatting constraints and
>   helper properties/methods for accessing useful parts of it. So that's
>   one piece of evidence that this approach isn't totally crazy.

No argument there, there are many such examples in the BCL.

## Final Thoughts

- There's nothing wrong with wrapping a value into a more complex type so that it may be described/manipulated with richer metadata.
- Centralizing validation in a single place is a good thing, but make sure you pick the right place.
- Crossing serialization boundaries can present challenges when logic resides within the type being passed.
- If you are mainly focused on trusting the input, you could use a simple wrapper class that lets the callee know that it is receiving data that has been validated. It doesn't matter where/how this validation has occurred.

ASP.Net MVC uses a similar paradigm for strings. If a value is `IMvcHtmlString`, it is treated as trusted and not encoded again. If not, it is encoded.

Comment: About the the `GetFriends` name: it was completely invented for my question - the signature was the focus more than the name - my application doesn't have anything to do with "friends." haha :) -- About "Scenario 2" and trusting my own API: if you use `string` everywhere, all it takes is one person forgetting in one location where they deserialize/parse a "special" string to properly format/transform/normalize that string for the error to silently bleed through the rest of the system. The `Username` example type, however, **guarantees** that can't happen by nature of the type.

Comment: Very good answer though, it's a candidate for the check mark of honor. ;)

Comment: Thanks. I'm certainly not against the paradigm as long as you are consistent and share the knowledge with anyone else using your code. I regularly encapsulate values in wrappers of various sorts.

Answer (score 3):

You have defined a base class for an **object representation** of something that can be parsed from a string. Make all members in the base class virtual, other than that it looks fine. You could consider managing serialization, case sensitivity etc. later on.

Such object representation is used in the base class library, for instance [System.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx):

```
Uri uri = new Uri("ftp://myUrl/%2E%2E/%2E%2E");
Console.WriteLine(uri.AbsoluteUri);
Console.WriteLine(uri.PathAndQuery);
```

Using this base class it's simple to implement easy access the the parts (like with System.Uri), strongly typed members, validation etc. The only downside I see is that multiple inheritance isn't allowed in c#, but you might not need to inherit any other class anyways.

Comment: Your example of the `System.Uri` class is very emboldening and (if it were not already in .NET!) it would actually be a great example for an application of this `TypedString<T>`. Also, good point about making all the methods of the base virtual.

Comment: IHtmlString is another good BCL example because it is nothing more than a string that is known to be HTML-encoded.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two downsides I can think of:

1) Maintenance developers may be taken by surprise. They may also just decide to use the CLR types, and then your codebase is split into code that uses `string username` in some places and `Username username` in others.

2) Your code may become cluttered with calls to `new Username(str)` and `username.Value`. This may not seem like much now, but the 20th time you type `username.StartsWith("a")` and have to wait for IntelliSense to tell you that something is wrong and then think about it and then correct it to `username.Value.StartsWith("a")` you might get annoyed.

I believe what you really want is what [Ada calls "constrained subtypes"](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Type_System), but I've never used Ada myself. In C#, the best you can do is a wrapper, which is less convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend another design.

Define a simple interface that describe a parsing rule (string syntax):

```
internal interface IParseRule
{
    bool Parse(string input, out string errorMessage);
}
```

Define the parsing rule for a user name (and the other rules that you have):

```
internal class UserName : IParseRule
{
    public bool Parse(string input, out string errorMessage)
    {
        // TODO: Do your checks here
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        {
            errorMessage = "User name cannot be empty or consist of white space only.";
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            errorMessage = null;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then add a couple of extension methods to that utilize the interface:

```
internal static class ParseRule
{
    public static bool IsValid<TRule>(this string input, bool throwError = false) where TRule : IParseRule, new()
    {
        string errorMessage;
        IParseRule rule = new TRule();

        if (rule.Parse(input, out errorMessage))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (throwError)
        {
            throw new FormatException(errorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void CheckArg<TRule>(this string input, string paramName) where TRule : IParseRule, new()
    {
        string errorMessage;
        IParseRule rule = new TRule();

        if (!rule.Parse(input, out errorMessage))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(errorMessage, paramName);
        }
    }

    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public static void DebugAssert<TRule>(this string input) where TRule : IParseRule, new()
    {
        string errorMessage;
        IParseRule rule = new TRule();
        Debug.Assert(rule.Parse(input, out errorMessage), "Malformed input: " + errorMessage);
    }
}
```

You can now write clean code that verifies syntax of strings:

```
    public void PublicApiMethod(string name)
    {
        name.CheckArg<UserName>("name");

        // TODO: Do stuff...
    }

    internal void InternalMethod(string name)
    {
        name.DebugAssert<UserName>();

        // TODO: Do stuff...
    }

    internal bool ValidateInput(string name, string email)
    {
        return name.IsValid<UserName>() && email.IsValid<Email>();
    }
```

Comment: How does this relate to "Scenario 2" in my question? It seems like the "guarantee" I refer to is lost here? - This approach also requires that every method that takes any of these "strongly typed" strings as input to remember to have a `CheckArg`/`DebugAssert` for each one.

Comment: The idea is that you check arguments when they enter your API. Internally you use debug conditional code that assert that your rules are fulfilled. In this way you minimize the need for parsing, you get clean code, and you'll discover bugs early as they will cause debug assertions to fail.